# Space length limitation

Tags: forms, ms-word, doc, word-2010

I have a word document file which is a form.

I try to complete it. Here is a screenshot of how it is looks like[image: example]

When I type in the grey box there is a limitation in length and when I reach it, it won't let me type more.

I am not sure of what it is, however I want to insert an image or a table but I can't.

How can I make it?

Comment: What ever action I tried I can't insert anything unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field you are trying to enter information into is a Legacy Text Form Field in Word 2010. In order to have a data entry area within the form that will accept text, tables, and images, delete this field and replace it with a Rich Text Content Control. This control is found on Word's Developer Tab:

[image: Word 2010 Developer Tab]

[Instructions for Displaying Word Developer Tab (if needed)](http://addbalance.com/word/developertab.htm#2010)

Like the legacy form fields, content controls allow manual or programmatic entry of data as well the ability to restrict editing of the data within the content control. Gregory K. Maxey has posted an incredibly detailed tutorial on creating forms with content controls, programming the content entry via VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) and restricting editing of the control's contents (all of which is available using the Rich Text Content Control):

[Create Forms with Content Controls by Gregory K. Maxey](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/content_control_fillin_form.html)

The same author also has an additional posting on content controls where he provides links to and offers explanations of more advanced content control abilities such as data mapping:

[Content Controls (Additional Information) by Gregory K. Maxey](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html)

Lastly, Microsoft also provides some guidance on programming content controls via .NET (which I think may be beyond the scope of your question, but which I include for future readers):

[MSDN: How to Add Content Controls to Word Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386200(v=vs.100).aspx)